# Android clickable panel UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently working on an Android app, I have completed all the 'hard stuff', such as getting my database working, and so on. Now I need to make the UI look decent.
I would like to make something that has a 'frame' layout that is clickable. You would click on a 'frame' to find out more information, a bit like the Amazon app.
If anyone has any ideas, tutorials or good links, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html). It's built in to Android and does what I think you're looking for (at least, it describes the Amazon app's UI; since `FrameLayout` has a very explicit meaning in Android that is not at all what you're talking about, I ignored that part).

**EDIT**: A screenshot would have been helpful but I think you're actually talking about a simple list-like view.

Oh. That's either a ListView, or more likely just a vertical LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. I can tell you what I'd do: Each item in the LinearLayout would have a background set, with a width of match_parent and a height of wrap_content, using a [9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) with the right-pointing arrow inside it. I'd also define an identical but blue-highlighted version of the image for the pressed state and use a [state drawable XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to let it know which to use. Then I'd just bind an onClick listener for each item I wanted to fire off a click action on.

Comment: I meant the layout that is presented when you click an item in the gallery.Sorry if I did not phrase it correctly.The 'frames' that present a bit of information with an arrow at the right hand side. I suppose I want to know what type of layout that is, nested Linear layouts? and how to achieve something similar.

Comment: Edited. You should also probably check out sample projects to understand what you can do, like Google's IO/2010 app at http://code.google.com/p/iosched/ or really any number of apps that ship with Android in the AOSP source code.

Comment: Thanks again Yoni, I'll check out the IO/2010 code and have a look. Some really good advice.I'd vote you up, but I don't have the rep yet, I'll get back to you in due course.